# Specific changes to LaTeX section titles

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec, sectsty

I need my whole document to be in 12pt font which I'm using sectsty for. My problem with that is related to the chapter, section, subsections titles. I'd like to make any of those titles ****bold** only** and 12pt. I can use titlesec but I'm not sure how to remove the chapter names, but then I can't coontrol the font size and make. If I use sectsty I can make it all 12pt but I can't remove the "chapter" from the document section.

I would like something like this:

> **DUMMY CHAPTER NAME**
>
> **1.1 Dummy section name**
>
> Bla bla bla section text

Here is what I have in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} % better for longer documents
\usepackage{graphicx} % required for inserting images
\usepackage{geometry} % required for changing margins
\usepackage{setspace} % for spacing of the lines
\usepackage{lipsum} % for fake text

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE}{\Large}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}


\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %for chemistry formulas

\usepackage{booktabs} % for tables

\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption} % for having table captions on top

\usepackage{enumerate} %for initial page counts
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % for numbering each section

\usepackage{natbib} % for citations
\setcitestyle{plainnat,open={(},close={)}} %Citation-related commands

\usepackage{fontspec} % changing font
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % choosing font

% for indenting the first line
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%for margins
\newgeometry{
top = 1in,
bottom = 1in,
outer = 1in,
inner = 1in
    }

\doublespacing

\begin{document}


\vspace*{\fill}
\begingroup
\begin{center}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
my awesome title \\
Submitted in partial fulfillment \\
of the requirements for the degree of \\
super smart person \\ 
in cool science stuff \\
at \\
school of cool science stuff \\
nice university \\
month 2024
} \end{center}
\endgroup
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/77956608/2777074